# GuzzleHttp response parsing with Laravel

Tags: php, parsing, dom, guzzle

I am using GuzzleHttp with Laravel to get a response.
The problem I have is in the response after I use the

```
        $client = new Client('http://idxbroker.com/');
        $response = $client->get('idx/featured')->send();
        $dom = $response->getBody();
```

It casts to a string, and I cannot figure a way to get the body element without the head....

i.e I just need the response BODY tag, and its contents to remain in HTML format.

I have tried using DomCrawler, and several ways with Guzzle, but I am evidently lacking the understanding of how to extract the Body element in tact

any help would be appreciated, and let me know if there is any clarification I can provide

Answer (score 0):

IDX Broker TOS actually doesn't allow your to scrape the pages. So I wouldn't do that. You can get the featured listings from the API. Here is the docs: http://middleware.idxbroker.com/docs/api/1.1/index.php